# Interpreting C++ autocorrelation code

Tags: c++, actionscript, frequency

I found this autocorrelation code, but I simply don't know what is "float_vec_t", for example. Is it a class or something? (I am trying to translate it to Action-script or JavaScript, which I know well)

```
class LPCAnalysis{
    public:
      float_vec_t LPCAnalysis::autoCorrelation(const float_vec_t &x);

};


/* Calculate the (UN-normalized) autocorrelation for a frame of a
signal   */

float_vec_t LPCAnalysis::autoCorrelation(const float_vec_t &x)
{
    short order=x.size();

    float_vec_t R(order);
    float sum;
    int i,j;

    for (i=0;i<order;i++) {
        sum=0;
        for (j=0;j<order-i;j++) {
            sum+=x[j]*x[j+i];
        }
        R[i]=sum;
    }
    return R;
}
```

below is my progress so far:

```
function LPCAnalysis (x:Array) {

    var order:int = x.length

    var R:Array= []
    var sum:Number
    var i:int
    var j:int

    for (i=0;i<order;i++) {
        sum = 0
        for (j=0;j<order-i;j++) {
            sum+=x[j]*x[j+i]
        }
        R[i] = sum
    }
    return R

}
```

Also, how can I extract the final frequency from the array R? (if R is an array). And what are the parameters that I should give to the function? An FFT result, a microphone signal?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find the declaration of `float_vec_t` to know for sure what is (although I imagine it's a `std::vector<float>`).  Try doing a global search of the source code to find where it's declared.

As for "extracting the frequency"; an autocorrelation doesn't give you the frequency directly.  You will need to perform an FFT on `R` (which will give you the *power spectral density*), and then search for a peak.  In practice, you may also need some other processing, like applying a *window function* to your data before you do all of this.

Comment: Really? FFT is incredibely imprecise! I was trying to run away from them using autocorrelation, and now you tell me that I will need them again =/ I asked here on stackoverflow how I could extract frequencies for a guitar tuner and the guys told me to use autocorrelation instead of FFT. If I'll have to use FFT anyway, why did they tell me that?

Comment: Autocorrelation is mathematically equivalent to the inverse FFT of the power spectrum, so there is no difference in "precision" between the two.

Comment: Really? I would discover that alone never. How can I extract the fundamental frequency from autocorrelation results?

Comment: Hey @Oliver Charlesworth, you mentioned "windowing" function in the context here. Can you give more information why windowing would be necessary here? I also do have a problem for an ergodic stationary random process which (based on a paper) uses windowing techniques as well but I only get the correct results for the mean values and not the standard deviation, hence, would be nice why you mention windowing here as well? Any references/literature?

Answer (score 2):

Based upon its usage, it is a Class/Object.  And It looks like its a standard Vector class for floats.

Yep on http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.dsp/2006-06/msg01218.html

I found this:

```
typedef std::vector<float> float_vec_t;
```

Which means that it is almost certainly a std::vector, Which in javascript just transfers to a standard object since javascript doesn't need any special handling for vectors.

Comment: A vector is like an array that can change size.  In C/C++ you must define the size of your array when you declare the array variable, unless your using pointers, but thats a whole other complicated area that's not important here.  So in effect the answer is yes, a javascript array is the same(essentially) as a C/C++ vector.